# Unterschied zwischen Benutzung und Verwendung

Tags: grammaticality

In welchen Fällen benutzt man Substantiv "die Benutzung" und wann die "Verwendung"? Danke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es sind sogar drei Substantive: die **Nutzung**, die **Benutzung** und die **Verwendung**. Alle drei sind praktisch bedeutungsgleich, die Nutzung der Worte Nutzung und Verwendung lässt allerdings auf einen größeren Wortschatz des Sprechers schließen.

Eine Ausnahme: Menschen zu nutzen oder zu benutzen ist abwertend gemeint, findet ein Mensch hingegen Verwendung bedeutet das umgekehrt, dass er sich irgendwo nützlich macht.

Answer (score 0):

Der Unterschied ist subtil, aber die Bedeutung scheint nicht genau dieselbe zu sein. In vielen Fällen sind die Wörter austauschbar, in einigen Fällen nicht. Ich würde die Frage auf die Verben zurückführen: *benutzen / verwenden*. Mein Eindruck ist: *benutzen* zielt auf eine bestimmte Funktion eines Gegenstands, hingegen *verwenden* auf den Gegenstand als ganzen, es kann also einen größeren Grad an Kontrolle über den Gegenstand bedeuten, unabhängig von einer einzelnen Funktion.

Zur Begründung: Kontaste mit den Beispielen im DWDS https://www.dwds.de/wb/benutzen bzw. https://www.dwds.de/wb/verwenden#d-1-1

Eher nur "benutzen", aber nicht "verwenden" (jew. DWDS-Zitate, man beachte die zusätzlichen Angaben, die auf besondere Funktionen der Gegenstände zielen)

- der Raum ist lange nicht benutzt worden
- diesen Weg benutze (= gehe) ich fast nie
- die Straßenbahn, das Schiff, den Zug benutzen (= damit fahren)
- Bücher gemeinsam, leihweise benutzen (= damit arbeiten)

Eher nur *verwenden*, nicht *benutzen*: die Formulierung "... auf etwas verwenden"

- seine Zeit nutzbringend verwenden
- er hat viel Zeit, Kraft, Fleiß, Mühe auf diese Arbeit verwandt, verwendet
- man sieht diesem selbstgebastelten Spielzeug an, wie viel Sorgfalt darauf verwandt wurde
- Geld(mittel) für etw. verwenden

(Nach meinem Gefühl sagt man eher "Geld verwenden", weil man es dabei komplett hergibt, nicht nur seine Funktion benutzt.)

Nach meiner Intuition austauschbar *verwenden* oder *benutzen* :

- ein Waschmittel, Präparat verwenden
- im Unterricht verwendet er dieses Lehrbuch
- diesen Teppich können wir nicht mehr verwenden
  (Letztes Beispiel jedoch: "den Teppich benutzen" zielt m.E. eher auf "darauf sitzen" etc., hingegen "den Teppich verwenden" darauf, dass man ihn überhaupt als Einrichtung in der Wohnung hat.